# CMake find_dependency does not respect the behaviour in the package documentation?

Tags: cmake, dependencies

Following documentation regarding [CMake package creation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-a-package-configuration-file), it is stated that:

> The `find_dependency` macro also sets `ClimbingStats_FOUND` to `False` if the dependency is not found, along with a diagnostic that the `ClimbingStats` package can not be used without the `Stats` package.

Yet, we are observing that this is only the case if `ClimbingStats` is requested from downstream without the `REQUIRED` argument.

### Not required

```
find_package(ClimbingStats CONFIG)
```

Then we get the behaviour described above, i.e.:

```
Found package configuration file:

    ...
```

but it set `ClimbingStats_FOUND` to `FALSE` so the package "ClimbingStats" is considered to be NOT FOUND.
    Reason given by package:

```
ClimbingStats could not be found because dependency Stats could not be found.
```

### Required

If we make the `ClimbingStats` package required instead:

```
find_package(ClimbingStats CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Then the error does not mention `ClimbingStats` at all

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Stats" with any of
  the following names:

    StatsConfig.cmake
    stats-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Stats" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Stats_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Stats"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

---

Are we misunderstanding the documentation linked above, or is this a bug in CMake behaviour?

Is there a way to require a package and still get the descriptive error message (like in the first example) when its upstreams are not found?

Answer (score 3):

> Are we misunderstanding the documentation linked above, or is this a bug in CMake behavior?

Looks like a bug in CMake **documentation**.

The documentation for [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) states:

> `find_dependency` forwards the correct parameters for `QUIET` and `REQUIRED` which were passed to the original `find_package()` call.

So, when outer `find_package()` was called with REQUIRED keyword, inner `find_package()` is called with that keyword too.

Exactly this behavior is observed in your case: the error message is generated by call

```
find_package(stats REQUIRED)
```

and the caller code has no chance to process its FALSE result for make the error message more descriptive.

---

> Is there a way to require a package and still get the descriptive error message (like in the first example) when its upstreams are not found?

As far as I understand, more "native" behavior of `find_dependency` would be to **not forward** `REQUIRED` keyword to the inner `find_package`, but check the result of that `find_package` *manually*, and emit appropriate message if it is FALSE.

You may submit feature request to CMake tracker about that.